# Support for Azure Managed Service Identity against Group resources

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been testing the new managed service identity (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity) and I can get a bearer token for the service identity just fine.

I have tried to add the service principal as an owner of an O365 Group, and tried to use the service principal to update the Group photo, but I get access denied. I did manage to list a group just fine.

I figured since app-only tokens won't work for updating a Group image, then a service principal might work as a work around.

My question is, would this be a supported scenario in the future as I don't want to use a regular account as a service account to work around this limitation.

Comment: Which scopes/permissions did you request for the token?

Comment: That's the thing it has it's own auth endpoint on `localhost:4141/MSI/token?resource=<resource uri>&api-version=2017-09-01` in Azure and seems it uses the rights on the underlying object somehow(?). So might be that it acts more as an app and less as a user. I have no idea of the magic implemented in Azure for this.

Comment: Per Marc, can you at least look inside the token, and see what roles claims (if any) are in the token and assigned to the app/MSI please?  I also have no idea about the magic going on here...

Comment: Sorry for not including the token, but it has no claims what so ever.

Comment: My guess it’s not a supported scenario. It worked with directory listing as I gave explicit permissions in AAD like in this post: https://gotoguy.blog/2017/09/21/using-azure-ad-managed-service-identity-to-access-microsoft-graph-with-azure-functions-and-powershell/